# I get a 404 error in an SPA React deployed in Nginx when enter to site not through the root (/)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nginx, http-status-code-404, single-page-application

### I get a 404 error in an Single Page Application (SPA) (React) deployed in Nginx behind reverse proxy Nginx when enter to site not through the root (/)

The application runs in the nginx docker container. This container is behind the reverse proxy Nginx.

When I login with root site `https://crm.mydomain.org`, first there is a redirect (in the application itself, not in nginx) to the third-party authorization service `https://account.careerum.com/`. After a successful login, I get to the primary section - `https://crm.mydomain.org/platform/#/clients`. Then I go through all the sections of the site perfectly. All other sections are as follows:
`https://crm.mydomain.org/platform/#/pagebuilder/pages`
`https://crm.mydomain.org/platform/#/analytics/sessions`
`https://crm.mydomain.org/platform/#/settings/common-settings`
etc.

But if I try to immediately go to any of these URLs, for example, `https://crm.givinschool.org/platform/#/pagebuilder/pages`, I get a `404 Not Found nginx / 1.21.1 error`.

I tried to insert in `location` -
`try_files $ uri $ uri / /index.html = 404;`
It does not help.

What else can I do to make the application work?

**Dockerfile** with which the application is built:

```
FROM node:14-buster as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.21.1
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /src/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

**Reverse Proxy Nginx** config for this site (**crm.conf**):

```
server {
    server_name crm.mydomain.org www.crm.mydomain.org;
    root /var/www/html/crm;
    proxy_send_timeout 240;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
    client_max_body_size 1G;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl "on";
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=10s;
        set $upstream "http://crm:80";
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html/crm;
    }

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.mydomain.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.mydomain.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = crm.mydomain.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name crm.mydomain.org;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import 'moment/locale/ru';

import React, { Suspense, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.scss';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from './i18n'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { store } from './redux/store';
import { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { interceptors } from '~/interceptors';
import { AppRoutes, StaticFilesRoutes } from './api/model';
import LoginRequired from './components/auth/login-required';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { userDetailsSelector } from './redux/selectors/auth.selectors';
import * as AuthActions from '~/redux/actions/auth-actions';
import ErrorBoundary from '~/shared/error-boundary/error-boundary';

// cookie (set cookie i18next=LANGUAGE)
// localStorage (set key i18nextLng=LANGUAGE)
// queryString(append ?lng=LANGUAGE to URL)
// htmlTag(<html lang=”LANGUAGE” …)
// path(http://example.site/LANGUAGE/...)
//

export const APP_CIPHER_KEY = 'Devas Team is building the brightest future!';

const PLATFORM_BASE_URL = '/platform/';

const App = React.lazy(() => import('./App'));
const OrderPaymentPage = React.lazy(() => import('./components/order-payment/'));

function BaseComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // auth state
  const userDetails: any = useSelector(userDetailsSelector);

  const setCookie = useCallback((isAuth, userDetails) => {
    // save user data and auth state
    dispatch(AuthActions.setUserAuth(isAuth));
    dispatch(AuthActions.setUserDetails(userDetails));

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  // http interceptors
  useEffect(interceptors, []);

  const reloadPage = () => <>{window.location.reload()}</>;

  return (
    <LoginRequired onAuth={setCookie}>
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path={AppRoutes.orderPayment}>
              <OrderPaymentPage userDetails={userDetails} />
            </Route>
            <Route path={PLATFORM_BASE_URL}>
              <App userDetails={userDetails} />
            </Route>
            <Route path={StaticFilesRoutes.PageInsertJS} render={reloadPage} />
            <Route path={StaticFilesRoutes.PageFormHandlerJS} render={reloadPage} />
            <Route path={StaticFilesRoutes.AppleDomainVerification} render={reloadPage} />
            <Route
              path="/"
              exact={true}
              component={() => <Redirect exact from="/" to={PLATFORM_BASE_URL} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Suspense>
    </LoginRequired>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <BaseComponent />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </Provider>
  </I18nextProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a question and realized that we have TWO nginx, one inside the container and one as a reverse proxy and we need to edit the config of what is inside the container and not a reverse proxy that simply passes requests through itself.

**Dockerfile** (add copy ./nginx/crm.conf)

```
FROM node:14-buster as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.21.1
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/crm.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /src/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

**Nginx config** (took the standard one and added - try_files )

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```